# TypeScript Build Module System of "None" won't stay on

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

Under the "TypeScript Build -> Module System" configuration in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, the Module System "None" won't stay on.  It always reverts back to "CommonJS".  I'm using the out of the box bundling in Visual Studio, and not the CommonJS system.  When it reverts back to CommonJS, my application will not run.  Why does this setting not stay put???

Comment: This problem appears to be fixed with Update 3 of Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is not present in VS 2017